EnvironmentObject instance apparently being re-created
I have a Swift app with a view as follows:
struct AddRecipe: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var rvm: RecipeViewModel

  var body: some View {
      Label("\(rvm.newRecipe?.name ?? "-")", systemImage: "pencil")
      Button("activate"){rvm.active = true}
  }
}

where I have
class RecipeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var active: Bool = false
    var newRecipe:Recipe?
}

and where the view is created from the parent view by:
NavigationLink(destination:AddRecipe().environmentObject(rvm),

When I present the controller, the recipe name correctly shows on the label, but when I click on the button, it is reset to being empty. In the debugger, I can see that the _seed property of the rvm object changes from 1 to 2, so it seems that I am getting a new object, which I don't understand as I thought EnvironmentObjects would provide me with a shared instance.

Please show a [mcve].

make sure the first rvm is a StateObject or has solid lifecycle management

Thanks -- I first instantiate it as: @StateObject var rvm = RecipeViewModel(), which I thought would be enough?

If the active state change is somehow triggering the view with the StateObject instantiation to be recreated that could cause this behavior. How does your app respond to the activation? If you move the StateObject instantiation up in the hierarchy does it make any difference? Alternatively, it might be helpful to know when the newRecipe.name is being set, as that could be a factor.

try learning to use the View and @State/@Binding for your view data. If you try to use your own objects you will basically be reimplementing those which is kinda a waste of time.
